# Rotate UIView and keep aspect ratio after rotation

Tags: objective-c, uiview, rotation

I want to rotate a UIView, but after the rotation the view is resized. I am using the autoresizing flag 'UIViewAutoresizingNone'.

Here is my code: (called from `layoutSubViews`)

```
- (void) setVerticalLabelFrame:(CGRect)r {

r.origin.y +=100.0f;
r.size.height = 20.0f;
r.size.width = 180.0f;
[[self rotatatingView] setFrame:r];
//[[self rotatatingView] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 4.0f)];
```

}

Here is the lazy initialization of the rotatingView.

```
- (UIView*)rotatatingView {
if (rotatatingView == nil) {
    rotatatingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [rotatatingView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [rotatatingView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
    [[self imageView] addSubview:rotatatingView];
}
return rotatatingView;
```

}

First shot is with the last line commented, second shot with the line uncommented.
Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be setting the `bounds` & `center` if you're setting a non-identity transformation matrix. As per [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816):

> Warning If this property is not the identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

So try something like this:

```
- (void) setVerticalLabelFrame:(CGRect)r {
    CGRect bounds = CGRectZero;
    bounds.size.height = 20.0f;
    bounds.size.width = 180.0f;

    CGPoint center;
    center.x = r.origin.x + (bounds.size.width / 2.0f);
    center.x = r.origin.y + (bounds.size.height / 2.0f) + 100.0f;

    [[self rotatingView] setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];

    [[self rotatingView] setCenter:center];
    [[self rotatingView] setBounds:bounds];

    [[self rotatingView] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 4.0f)];
}
```

Comment: That didn't really help. Its still resized.

Comment: Hmm. Can you show us what `rotatingView` is then please? How is it defined, etc?

Comment: updated the original post with my lazy initialization code for the rotatingView.

Comment: What happens if in `setVerticalLabelFrame:` you set the transform of `rotatingView` to `CGAffineTransformIdentity` before setting the centre and bounds?

Comment: Thank you very much sir! That helped. Could you add that to your answer, then I accept it and rate it up! Nvm, added it!